# Which party has more supports from ethnic Indians in the USA?

Tags: united-states

Between Democrat and Republican, which party has more votes/activists from [ethnic East Indians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Americans)?

Explain, Why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indian Americans generally vote with Democrats. https://www.npr.org/2020/02/22/808404879/one-group-whose-political-leanings-may-be-changing-indian-americans-who-are-hind?t=1594291812362

However there is a developing religious divide, between Muslims and Hindus.  With socially conservative Hindu Americans, who may identify with conservative parties in India, such as the BJP, tending also to identify with the Republican party in the USA, while Muslims have been demonised by Trump and tend to be strong "anti-Trump" voters.

There are also signficant other factors. Owing to immigration policies, many Indian Americans are college-educated, urban (tend Democrat), and high earners (tend Republican).  These correlate with political attitudes, but not all in the same direction.

So "Indian Americans" don't vote as a bloc, they tend to vote on issues unrelated to ethnicity.